# TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueSeq' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, lodash, reactive-programming, immutable.js

I'm getting a strange Error in React.js. Not sure if it's because Im using immutable as a package. But either way heres the errors:

```
Store.getMessages
src/store.js:26
  23 |   this.update()
  24 | }
  25 | getMessages(){
> 26 |   return this.messages.valueSeq()
  27 | 
  28 | }
  29 | addChannel(index, channel = {}){
View compiled
Messenger.render
src/components/messenger.js:91
  88 |   height: height,
  89 | };
  90 | 
> 91 |   const messages = store.getMessages()
  92 |   const channels = store.getChannels()
  93 | 
  94 |   return (
View compiled
▶ 24 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
src/index.js:9
   6 | import './css/app.css'
   7 | 
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  10 | registerServiceWorker();
  11 | 
  12 | 
View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but if I had to assume what your problem is you'll see here you have your `getMessages()` function.

```
getMessages() {
  return this.messages.valueSeq();
}
```

Now, there's not necessarily a problem with this function itself at all. The problem is further up in that it seems as if `this.messages` is undefined. If this.messages is your initial state, have you initialized it yet? If no, that is likely your issue. Either way, in your store `this.message` equals undefined at the time `getMessages` is being called in `messages.js`. No functions can exist on an undefined variable which is why you're getting that error. If you could provide more of your store code, I could probably help you more but these small little sections make it difficult to tell why `this.messages` is undefined.